# Oracle Linux 8 getting DHCP but DNS not updating

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dhcp, rhel8

My Oracle Linux 7 boxes automatically get a DHCP address and then BIND9 DNS is updated successfully.

I recently installed an Oracle Linux 8 box, and while it is successfully assigned a DHCP ip address, BIND9 DNS is not being updated causing nslookups, dig etc to fail for the Oracle Linux 8 box.

Has something changed in RHEL 8 about the way that dynamic DHCP-DNS works with the RHEL 8 box ?  Because the RHEL 7 boxes are working fine, getting DHCP ip and then DNS is updated automatically, it seems like it must be something about the RHEL 8 box ?

Thanks!

Comment: used tcpdump and DHCP address is being handed out fine.

Comment: When I run "tcpdump -vnes0 -i eth0 port 67 or port 53 or port 68" on the DNS-DHCP box for Oracle Linux 7 clients requesting DNS-DHCP, I see plenty of traffic on port 68 and 53.  But when the Oracle Linux 8 client requests DNS-DHCP, there is no port 53 traffic at all, and although the Oracle Linux 8 client gets a DHCP ip address, the DNS server is not updated so there is no name resolution.